# Memory Consumption Steadily Increases for Empty Project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've found something quite strange in my application. I've noticed that the Memory (private working set) column in Task Manager's Details tab (Windows 8.1) shows that my app's memory usage just keeps going up and up and up. It does not stop.

It starts off at around 3,000K and after just 4 - 5 minutes it's already at 44, 000K. That's practically 44MB in just a few minutes.

I've never noticed this in any of my apps before, so I didn't know exactly what to do (if there are any tools that I could use to identify the problem, is there is one) so I began looking at pieces of code where I've opened a new form, or created new objects that implement IDisposable and found that I have disposed of all things that there is a Dispose for. I have not left anything go unchecked.

So then I just began removing entire sections of code in order to try and see what could be causing the mem to go up so much so quickly. But nothing was working. So then I removed 3 entire Forms which left me with just the MainForm (Form1).

Nothing changed. App still uses too much memory - this wouldn't bother me so much if it didn't keep using more and more and more and more.

So then I deleted all the code in the MainForm.

So now I have an *empty project* with 1 *empty Form*.

And guess what? It still uses too much memory. And it still steadily increases at about 20 - 60kb per second and it just never stops.

How do I track this down? How do I stop it?

I've made so many apps and I can even open all the apps I've made right now and just stare at task manager and watch the memory column stay at the same value.

As I said, there is no code. All I have is an empty form (with a few PictureBoxes on it - *nothing else*):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SManager
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this under the debugger? Does a completely empty (e.g. *new*) project exhibit the same?

Comment: The form is not really *empty*, which controls you have on it and how are these configured? I am thinking about resources in form (gif-animations for `PictureBox`es).

Comment: There are 4 PictureBox controls on the form. One of them is a 2kb GIF animation. I don't know what you mean by configured - all I did was place 4 PictureBox controls on the form and added images to them using the Properties Pane. This happens through the debugger and also when I run the app's .exe from the Debug/Release folders.